# Letter-spacing in large name decreasing

Tags: c#, fonts

I have such trouble: in large names, as shown in image[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/2c46b75236.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/2c46b75236.jpg)

, somehow letter-spacing for Tahoma font is decreasing.
This issue is shown up in two components that I use, so I don't think this is bug of the components.
I have tested with another fonts, 
Arial - situation the same;
MS Sans Serif - the same;
Trebuchet MS - situation is good, symbols type correctly;
Times New Roman - situation is good too, but font with notches
Can you help? Using .NET without WPF.

Comment: The letter spacing is called 'kerning' in font terminology, which might help you find more relevant answers to your problem

Answer (score 0):

What controls are you using? Are these them:

- [Elegant Grid](http://www.prof-uis.com/elegant-grid/overview.aspx)
- [GtkTreeView](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/unstable/GtkTreeView.html)

You've only shown one screen shot there. Which control is that?

Any chance of some example source code? Something which shows the behaviour in GtkTreeView would be best as it's free...

Comment: GTLTreeView, Elegant Grid as you can see it's two different third-party's components

Comment: Can you post a minimal code snippet which reproduces the problem?

Comment: http://www.glacialcomponents.com/ProdDetail/gtl.aspx
Glacial TreeList
On screenshot is shown GTL.
I don't know what source code might be posted here it's just visualization of font.